# Нужна ли запятая в предложени

Tags: пунктуация

А надлежащий уход и вовремя принятые меры борьбы с врагами(,) надолго сохранят красоту вашего жилища.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Не нужна.
Я даже боюсь предположить, почему можно было в этом усомниться.
Вообще ***между подлежащим и сказуемым одиночной запятой не бывает***. Никогда.